# Delete cookies in Firefox after a specified time frame

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookie

In the Firefox tab `Privacy` in Preferences we can set `Accept cookies from sites` and then `Keep until:` `they expire`, `I close Firefox` or `ask me everytime`.

Currently I have *keep cookies until they expire* but I'd like to be able to select a time frame, for instance 40 days; so cookies with be automatically deleted once they lived for 40 days. Is this possible? I couldn't find an option for this in `about:config` but perhaps I didn't look in the right place.

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/281517/delete-cookies-in-firefox-after-specific-interval-of-time claims "network.cookie.lifetimePolicyto" and "network.cookie.lifetime.days"

Comment: @Rinzwind: [network.cookie.lifetimePolicy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.lifetimePolicy) and [network.cookie.lifetime.days](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.lifetime.days) solves it.

Comment: cool added as an answer so it can be marked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"network.cookie.lifetimePolicyto" and "network.cookie.lifetime.days are what you are [looking](https://superuser.com/questions/281517/delete-cookies-in-firefox-after-specific-interval-of-time) for. Kudos to Echo419@superuser.