# How do you defrag and remove cookies on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I would like to know how you defragment and remove cookies on Ubuntu.

Comment: Regarding the "defrag", it has been asked before http://askubuntu.com/questions/221079/how-to-defrag-an-ext4-filesystem Cookies in FF http://askubuntu.com/questions/580840/delete-cookies-in-firefox-after-a-specified-time-frame  Same from terminal http://askubuntu.com/questions/368325/how-to-clear-browsers-cache-and-cookies-from-terminal Chrome: http://askubuntu.com/questions/628460/how-to-delete-temp-files-which-is-created-by-google-chrome-in-linux

Comment: Do you [need](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221079/how-to-defrag-an-ext4-filesystem) to defrag or [want](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary) to?

Comment: As far as cookies go, use Bleachbit.

Comment: Defragmentation is rarely required on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Firefox cookies:

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
```

Rremove Chrome cookies:

```
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```